# understanding conditional density functions

Tags: probability

I am studying conditional probabilities, and I need to make sure that what I understood is correct or not.
Assume we have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with conditional density function
$f_{X|Y}(x|y)$

what I understand is that this density is a function of $x$ only, and that it can have different values or versions depending on the value of $Y$ that we are conditioning on. For example, we can have
$f_{X|Y} (x|Y=a) $ $\quad$  and $\quad$    $f_{X|Y} (x|Y=b)$

which are different functions depending on the value of $Y$.

Is my understanding correct, or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Indeed, the CDF $$F_{X | Y}(x | y) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_{X|Y}(t|y) dt$$ should be considered as function of $x$ only.

In some sources ([here](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/conditional-probability-distributions#hid3) for example) to highlight that the following equivalent expression is used:

$$F_{X | Y = y}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_{X|Y = y}(t) dt$$

That is if we change $y$ then we will get a different distribution.

Comment: thank you for your reply, would this be valid if Y takes its values from a set, like this: $f_{X|Y}(x|Y\in B)$

Comment: I thinks yes because the set $K = \{\omega: Y(\omega) \in B \}$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable if $B \in \mathbb{R}$ ($\mathcal{F}$ is sigma-algebra on $\Omega$). You can write that $$F_{X|K}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f_{X|K} (t) dt, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$. Again, if we change set K then we will get a different distribution.

Comment: typo: I mean $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, not $B \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: do I need to use another integral for set $B$?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean exactly but functions $f_{X|K}$ and $f_{X|Y=y}$ are different so the integrals (CDF) are different too. There is no simple way for finding $f_{X|K}$. On the other hand you can always find $$f_{X|Y=y}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$$
if joint density $f_{X,Y}$ exists.

Comment: I mean, can I find $f_{X|K}$ by integrating $f_{X|Y=y}$ over $K$ ?

Comment: No. To find $f_{X|K}$ you should use the following formula:
$$f_{X|K}(x) = \frac{P(K | X= x)f_X(x)}{P(K)}$$

Comment: OK, I get it now. Thanks